# Jquery backgroundPosition Animation Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using Jquery to animate an object while the user presses a key.

Upon Keyup the object stops moving, but I need to know what the background position of the object is when it stops. Using .stop(true);

Without getting to much into it, I need to be able to get the position of the background.  Is there anyway with Javascript or jquery to obtain those numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are changing the background position coordinates, you will be able to get the *computed style* of the element, at the moment you stop the animation simply by using the [`css`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) method.

It will return you a pair of pixel values separated by a space, something like "Xpx Ypx", you can split that values and use them separately:

```
var position = $(selector).css('backgroundPosition').split(' '),// ["0px", "0px"]
x = position[0], y = position[1];
```

Comment: what kind of variable is x? I tried doing x + someInt and it ended not adding integers, but seems like it was concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to identify the specific element that has the background image.  Then you can use .offset - http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset - to get the left/top absolute position of the element with respect to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#yourOject').css('backgroundPosition')
```

It should return something like "nnpx yypx".

Answer (score -1):

```
var position = $(selector).css('backgroundPosition').split(' '),// ["0px", "0px"]
x = position[0], y = position[1];
```

This was almost perfect, The only thing I changed was split('px') so that your able to have the raw number when you use it for other calculations.